# Amazon Machine Image

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-ami

I have a website running on the Singapore AWS servers. It is an EC2 instance and the website is built using django configured with Apache and MySQL. I took an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the instance running the website, copied the AMI to the N. Virginia location and launched a new EC2 instance using that AMI at N.Virginia. Since it's a complete machine image, I expect to see my site when I visit the Public DNS of the new server in N. Virginia. However, I'm getting a `Bad Request (400)`. Any ideas?

Apache error log:

```
[Fri Jul 25 14:51:19.903606 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1114] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jul 25 17:29:53.560742 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1230] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6$
[Fri Jul 25 17:29:53.704627 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1230] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jul 25 17:36:53.240811 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1230] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jul 25 17:36:54.206135 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11154] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.$
[Fri Jul 25 17:36:54.206278 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11154] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Yes but I don't understand it...which is why I'm here. The log is edited into the question above.

Answer (score 1):

So I firgured it out. You need to change the host in the apache config file and the settings.py file to your new public DNS.